# Easy-to-describe example of uncomputable function

Tags: turing-machines, computability

After teaching my philosophy of cognitive science undegraduates what a Turing machine is, I mentioned that there are functions that can't be computed using a Turing machine.  A curious philosophy major asked for an example of such a function.  Most of the students in the class are not CS students and need not be mathematically adept, so I am limited as to what I can say, except to those students who want to hear more outside of class.

The only example of a particular function that is uncomputable that I could come up with off the top of my head was the halting problem, but that would have required a substantial digression, and it would seem quite obscure to most of the students if I walked them through it.  It would also not be sufficiently useful to explain to the class why there must be uncountably many functions that are not Turing-computable.  (First step: teach the countable/uncountable distinction.)

Is there an example of an uncomputable function that's relatively easy to describe and understand--more so than the halting problem?

Comment: Post correspondence problem?

Comment: Given a multivariate polynomial $p$, is there a way to assign an integer to each of the variables such that $p$ evaluates to 0? This problem, finding solutions to "Diophantine equations", was shown to be hard by the MRDP theorem. A fun example of when Diophantine equations go crazy is [discussed here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-frac-x-y+z-+-frac-y-z+x-+-frac-z-x+y-4/answer/Alon-Amit) (note that you can multiply through by (+)(+)(+) to get something in the form of a polynomial). That particular puzzle has an extra positivity requirement.

Comment: Calculating the last digit of pi?

Answer (score 3):

A classic example of an uncomputable function is *The Busy Beaver Problem*: For each N, consider all N-state Turing Machines over the alphabet { [blank], 1 }; over all of those machines which always halt when started on a blank tape, find one which leaves the maximum possible number of 1's on the tape once it has halted; then f(N) is that number of 1's.

Comment: Still not simple or intuitive enough to be obviously of use with my students, but it is relatively simple.  Thanks PMar.  As with Yuval Filmus's and Yonathan N's suggestions, I can think about whether there's a good way to present it.

Answer (score 2):

The proof that Radò's function $\Sigma(n)$ (maximal number of 1 written by an $n$ state Turing machine starting on a tape of all 0s before halting) isn't computable is rather simple, once you have a few building blocks. First, by convention Turing machines start in state 1 and halt by moving to the (non-existent) state $n + 1$ (so you can build a machine that does $M_1$ then $M_2$, written $M_1 \mid M_2$, by just renumbering the states of $M_2$ and copying it after $M_1$). Represent number $N$ by $N$ ones starting at the current head's position. Build a machine $\mathtt{Twice}$ that starts with $N$ on the tape and stops at the start of $2 N$ (can build $\mathtt{Dup}$, that copies $N$ after itself separated by a 0 -- can be done by overwriting 1 with 0, move to the end and add a 1, go back to the second 0, replace by 1 and go for the next 1, repeat until you hit 0, then move back to the start --, compose it with $\mathtt{Add}$ that adds $M$ + $N$ separated by a single 0 by just squashing them together then moving to the beginning), a machine $\mathtt{Inc}$ that increments the number on the tape (very simple, move to the first 0, write a 1 there, move back to the first 1), will also need machines $\mathtt{Write}_n$ which writes $n$ on the tape and stops at it's beginning (can be done in $n$ states, just write a 1 and move left $N$ times; we will run this at the start, so it doesn't matter if it messes up the tape). Now assume there is a machine $\Sigma$ that reads $n$ and writes out $\Sigma(n)$. Compose $\mathtt{Twice} \mid \Sigma \mid \mathtt{Inc}$, say the result has $N$ states. Then $\mathtt{Write}_N \mid \mathtt{Twice} \mid \Sigma \mid \mathtt{Inc}$ has $2 N$ states, but writes $\Sigma(2 N) + 1$, contradiction.

Comment: vonbrand, is this different from the Busy Beaver problem mentioned by @PMar?  (Either way, probably more involved than what I needed, optimally, for my students.)

Comment: @Mars, the Busy Beaver competiton is to find a Turing machine with $n$ states that writes the most ones on the tape before halting. It is related, but not the same: the machine hipotesized here would write $\Sigma(n)$ *contiguous* ones.